# how i use all space in macbook

Tags: macos

[image: I see i have 750 GB but i can use only 502gm why]

hello i leave this macbook over a years ago and i back to use it now

but i realize i have 750GB and i can use only 502GB

how i use it all this 750 gb??
i try many way but i cant

i try run bootcamp but i cant do anything with it

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage ArabFox                 501.6 GB   disk0s4
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS ArabFox                +501.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s4
                                 9FDF63DB-3DB0-4319-AF3F-CD3334E94151
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: Try `diskutil cs resizestack 9FDF63DB-3DB0-4319-AF3F-CD3334E94151 0`

Comment: Error: -69742: The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small; please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? What is the model year of the Mac? To proceed, you will need to add to your question the output from `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. Depending the version of macOS, you may need to disable System Integrity Protection before entering this command.  However, ever if you post this output, the next step would probably be to erase everything and reload macOS.